# Track last known location of iPad mini (2) without "Find My Phone"

Tags: ipad, geolocation

I recently seem to have lost my iPad mini. I had expected Apple to have some functionality for lost devices enabled by default, but I notice that I cannot use Find My Phone via the iCloud interface, as I had not enabled the service myself.

I am wondering whether I could somehow retrieve my GPS location history, though, so I can at least find out in what country I have lost it (I was travelling form Switzerland to Germany, and if my iPad made it with me to Germany, it should have reconnected to the network there). This used to be possible with Android devices over Google Latitude. Is it somehow possible for Apple devices?

Also, is there any way I can block my iPad? Or any other location/blocking functionality which I can use at this point?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not set up any tracking service, then you will not be able to track the device. The device does not save its location history to the cloud without such a service being set up.

If your iPad had a SIM card, you can able to talk to the provider who may be able to tell you where the device is — not as accurate as GPS but will give you an idea of the country at the very least.

You're not going to be able to 'block' the iPad either since you haven't activated Find my iPhone, but the SIM card provider can block the SIM card.

Comment: I think you are wrong in stating that the iPad does not have GPS. I was in Switzerland with no connection to any network the whole day, but managed to navigate on my downloaded Google Maps quite nicely. AFAIK that would have to be the GPS.

Comment: @TheChymera Only iPads with cellular have GPS since the GPS is built in to the cellular module. The iPads without cellular use Wi-Fi triangulation.

Comment: As I said, I was not connected to any networks, and I got ~accurate location info. Are you saying my iPad also had 3G?

Comment: @TheChymera You don't have to be connected to the network for the triangulation to take place. If your iPad has a SIM card then it is the 3G model.

Comment: Ok, so it had both 3G and GPS then, but as you said, this does not help me, yes?

Comment: @TheChymera The SIM card provider may help — I've edited my answer.

Comment: apparently they cannot - I assume they have their SIMs location history, but are not allowed to disclose it. Any advice on how I can be more convincing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13989/discussion-between-grgarside-and-thechymera)